# Issue getting correct $(this) element to append to a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, detach

I have an div field that when clicked in, creates a drop down menu. Whenever you click on the drop down option choices, the name will go to the div field `#proposal-type`. You can keep clicking to add additional option choices.

My issue is, when I click on the x to remove the choice, I cannot figure out how to get the entire `drop-item` that was just click on to be removed and fill back into the drop down list. Right now only the x is going back into the option list.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Also, could someone please share a quick pointer of how to get the option box list to go away when I click outside of it? It just remains there no matter what right now.

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/xrrpw1mq/)

```js
$('#proposal-type').click(function() {
  $('#proposal-type-drop').addClass('active');
});
$('#proposal-type').text("Type of Project *");
$('.drop-item-input').on('change', function() {
  var proposalVal = "";
  var proposalHtml = "";
  $('.drop-item-input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      proposalVal += $(this).val();
      proposalHtml += '<div class="drop-item-selected"><span class="drop-item-close"></span>' + $(this).val() + '</div>';
      $(this).closest('label').fadeOut();
    };
    //else if ($(this).is(":checked") === false) {
    // $(this).closest('label').fadeIn();
    //};
    $('#proposal-type').val(proposalVal).html(proposalHtml);
    $('#proposal-type-drop').removeClass('active');
  });
  //values
  var type = $('.drop-item-input:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get().join(', ');
  console.log(type);
});
$(document).on('click', '.drop-item-close', function() {
  console.log("Triggered");
  $(this).fadeOut("medium", function() {
    $(this).detach().appendTo('#proposal-type-drop').fadeIn();
  });
  $(this).is(":checked") === false;
  $(this).closest('label').fadeIn();
  $(this).closest('.drop-item-selected').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.panel-input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 1.5% 2% 2.5% 2%;
}

.proposal-input {
  width: 100%;
}

#proposal-type-drop {
  width: 45%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#proposal-type-drop.active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.drop-item {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.drop-item-input {
  display: none;
}

.drop-item-selected {
  background: #0085A1;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.drop-item-close {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT8/xnA/dT8xnAqAc.png");
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: ease 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-input">
  <div id="proposal-type" class="proposal-input"></div>
  <div id="proposal-type-drop">
    <label class="drop-item">Apple<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type[]" class="drop-item-input" value="Apple"></label>
    <label class="drop-item">Banana<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type[]" class="drop-item-input" value="Banana"></label>
    <label class="drop-item">Cake<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type[]" class="drop-item-input" value="Cake"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In a click handler, `this` refers to the element that was clicked, which was the X.  You should be able to use `this` to locate the correct value though `$(this).parent().text()` or similar

Comment: @James Thanks for the help. I somewhat figured it out, with your advise, but it starts to get messed up when you try to add an item back to the selected status .. https://jsfiddle.net/xrrpw1mq/1/

Comment: Also, I cannot seem to figure out how to remove the checked value associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here, that I've tried to correct. I should warn you right of the start though, this feels very hacked together as I didn't want to try and rewrite your code, you might want to look into a different approach, maybe without using checkboxes as they seem to overcomplicate the system.

The **first issue** is as James said in his comment, in that, the reason you're only getting the cross appear in the dropdown is due to selecting the cross with `$(this)` when you're actually looking for the parent, achievable through `$(this).parent()`.

The **second issue** is that in your second [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrrpw1mq/1/), you have corrected the first issue, however, your code doesn't quite work, since you're now inserting a different type of element that doesn't contain a checkbox into your drop-down element, resulting in a whole heap of trouble when you attempt clicking on it. The way of rectifying this issue is by inserting a new HTML element as you did in a previous section of your code and removing the old element in the list. Resulting in the following modification to your `.drop-item-close` eventListener method;

```
$("#proposal-type-drop input[value='"+$(this).parent().text()+"']").remove();
$("#proposal-type-drop").append('<label class="drop-item">'+$(this).parent().text()+'<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type[]" class="drop-item-input" value="'+$(this).parent().text()+'"></label>').fadeIn();
$(this).parent().detach();
```

This brings us to our **third issue** as now we've generated a new element and it looks great in the drop-down list, however, it won't respond to your previous `.drop-item-input` eventListener. We require modifying this listener to also cope with dynamically added elements, in the following way;

```
$(document).on('change', '.drop-item-input', function() {
    /* Rest of your code */
});
```

Here is an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrrpw1mq/2/) containing these modifications and it should work as you intended.

Comment: Thanks for the help and great explanation! I really appreciate the help!